# Loop list of objects in getJSON method - jQuery, asp.net mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have below code to process List returned from getJSON method.

```
public class class1
{
   public int id {get; set;};
   public string name {get; set;};
}

public JsonResult MethodName(string param1, string parm2)
{
  List<Class1> results = GetClassResults();
  return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}

$.getJSON("/Controller/MethodName",
            {
                param1: val1, param2: val2
            }
            , function (data) {

                $.each(data, function () {

                });

            });
```

I have each function to loop the results, but i don't know how to get list of id's and names returned.

Can you please help?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try a `console.log(data)` in your `callback function` and check the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this (It may look [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/w5pzM/2/)):

```
var ids = [], names = [];
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    ids[key] = value.id;
    names[key] = value.name;
    // Check in the loop by un-commenting this line
    // console.log('id: ' + value.id  + ' name: ' + value.name);
});

// Print out arrays
console.log(ids); // an array of ids
console.log(names); // an array of names
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON("/Controller/MethodName", {param1: val1, param2: val2}, 
 function (data) {
    $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
        console.log('id: ' + value .id  + ' name: ' + value .name);
     });
 });
```

`data` is the entire array coming back.  $each is called once for each item, which is passed as a parameter to the inline function.